# How to authenticate users into internal application with Google Apps

Tags: php, authentication, google-apps, gdata, zend-gdata

I am creating an application within our company that handles all our processing. This will need to implement Google Apps (we have premier).

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to authenticate user. I need full access to ALL their information (add, delete, modify [calendars, emails, contacts[, password?]]). I'm wanting to do something along the lines of OAuth so that they don't need to store their password on my server as well as google. As if it's all 1 concurrent login.

I'm using Zend to communicate with Gdata API.

What's the best kind of authentication for my application? What are limitations to this authentication?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-legged OAuth allows the trusted applications on the domain to access user data without the user's explicit intervention.

See http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html#2LeggedOAuth